# Retrieving value from Mongodb query response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb aggregation framework query as shown below.I am unable to parse the output of the below query

```
 myModel.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": { "$and": [{ "serviceActiveFlag": "Y" }, { "hospitalName": hospitalName }] }
        },
        //decompile array
        { $unwind: "$Treatment" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$Treatment.departmentName", "procedureList": {
                    $push: { "procedureName": "$Treatment.name", "cost": "$Treatment.costLowerBound" }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "_id": 0,
                "department": '$_id',
                "procedureList": 1
            }
        }

    ], function (err, result) {

    })
```

Output of the above query is shown below

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "procedureList": [
                {
                    "procedureName": "Root Canal",
                    "cost": 10200
                }
            ],
            "department": "Dental"
        },        
        {
            "procedureList": [
                {
                    "procedureName": "Bone Grafting",
                    "cost": 20000
                }
            ],
            "department": "Ortho"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do i retrieve the value corresponding to key `data`?

I tried result.data[0],but I got undefined error

Expected output is given below

Expected output

```
[
        {
            "procedureList": [
                {
                    "procedureName": "Root Canal",
                    "cost": 10200
                }
            ],
            "department": "Dental"
        },        
        {
            "procedureList": [
                {
                    "procedureName": "Bone Grafting",
                    "cost": 20000
                }
            ],
            "department": "Ortho"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: try `result.toObject().data[0]` . And let me know if it worked. I will explain.

Comment: have you tried just `result.data`?

Comment: All your examples show actual Javascript arrays and objects. There is no JSON anywhere - JSON is a `string` format that contains encoded data. To work with the data you simply extract it. Do you have a JSON **string**? If so, parse it. If not, remove the "JSON" from headline and tag. **Your description is in direct contradiction to the data you show us!!**

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to parse the json-data, that's why it isn't able to index, Please use the code below to parse the json and then try accessing the array. if you encounter any problems, please mention them.

```
result = JSON.parse(result)
result.data[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Result is an object so,

```
let data = result.data
```

Comment: Ideally your solution should work.Unfortunately it's not working in my case.Result is the object returned by mongodb aggregation query